# How do I cause an animation every 5 seconds using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay so I don't have much experience with jQuery. What I'm trying to do here is make the background of the page change every 5 seconds (10 seconds actually but 5 is for testing). Along with this I want a countdown animation, like a bar below on the page. I've got the background changing every 5 seconds but I cant get the bar animations working. It only occurs once or twice but then never happens again :////

this is the code for the bar animation

```
var initialWidth = 0;
var initialHeight = 0;

var firstMeasurements = function(){
  initialHeight = $(".countdown").height() + "px";
  initialWidth = $(".countdown").width() + "px";
}

$(function(){
        var bar = $(".countdown");

        function countdown() {
              bar.animate({"width":"0px"}, 5000);
        }

        function restartCountdown() {
              bar.css("width", initialWidth);
              countdown();
              setTimeout(restartCountdown, 5000);
        }

        bar.css("height", initialHeight);
        restartCountdown();
});
```

"countdown" is the class of the div that I want to animate every 5 seconds.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? 
thank you.

Comment: You are looking for [`setInterval();`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Comment: You need to invoke `firstMeasurements` in document ready handler

Comment: @D4V1D, OP is using recursion i.e. invoke `restartCountdown` inside `restartCountdown` so `setInterval` is not required

Comment: @Satpal: Thanks for pointing that out though `setInterval();` shouldn't be more accurate to achieve what the OP wants?

Comment: @D4V1D, Agreed `setInterval` will be more accurate.

Comment: Thank you @D4V1D :)  setInterval() is very helpful indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete code [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bvaqrmxf/)

```
$(function () {
        var firstMeasurements = {
            width: $("#countdown").css('width'),
            height: $("#countdown").css('width')
        }
        var startAnim = function () {
            $("#countdown").animate({
                "width": "0px", "height": "0px"
            }, 5000, resetAnim)
        }
        var resetAnim = function () {
            $("#countdown").css({
                "width": firstMeasurements.width,
                "height": firstMeasurements.height
            });
            startAnim();
        }
        startAnim()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... This should be enough to get you started :)

```
var time = 3000, //3 seconds
var timer = setInterval(function(){ 
    alert("Hello"); 
}, time);

//Why declare the interval as timer var?
//Because you may wish to cancel it at some point by doing
//clearInterval(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
setTimeout(restartCountdown, 5000);
```

You should use:

```
setInterval(restartCountdown, 5000);
```

Because `setTimeOut()` will fire only once, but `setInterval()` will always fire every 5 seconds.

**Note:**

In your case you are calling `restartCountDown()` recursively, so if you will use `setInterval()` you need to change your function to the following:

```
    function restartCountdown() {
          bar.css("width", initialWidth);
          setInterval(countdown, 5000);
    }
```

This way you will initialize the width then fire `countdown()` after  5 seconds.

Comment: Note: OP is using recursion i.e. invoke `restartCountdown` inside `restartCountdown` so `setInterval` is not required

Comment: function countdownLoop(interval){setTimeout(countdownLoop, interval);}

Answer (score -1):

Ohoh. The Every-N-seconds question ;)

Actually today you only can use `setTimeInterval``

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("5 secs have passed"); 
}, 5000/*5000 ms=5 seconds*/);
```

**But care ! your Javascript can do nothing else during the `setInterval`.
Browser javascript runs in a single thread.** So if you perform something that takes too long - it will freeze browser.

Future of Javascript will bring multi-thread.

To be able to do things during you wait 5 seconds, I have used strategies like asynchronous request. Well, fell free to ask if you dont want to be frozen during the 5 secs.

Some reads ? http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/